# Modify private data in a base class without a setter, c++ visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am working on a project for my computer science class where we create a photomosaic of a source image. We have been given a base image class. Along with the standard constructors, this class contains getter functions to return the private pixel array data and image height and width. We were told to create a derived class for all of the filler images, which need to be stored in a linked list. I've got the majority of the program worked out, but I don't know how to replace blocks of the source image with the pixel data from a filler image.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"  //needed for the Windows display
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include "globals.h"  //some global variables are included here
    #include "pixel.h"  //includes the pixel class for storing individual pixels
    #include "image.h"  //includes the image class we will be using.
    #include "fillerImage.h" //includes the fillerImage
    #include "fillNode.h"
    #include <sstream>


image* mosaic = displayed;  //displayed is the current image in the gui, mosaic is the copy that will be the photomosaic
pixel** mospix = mosaic->getPixels();  
pixel** headpix = head->data->pix;   //I created a public member pixel** in the filler image class with the hope that I could use it to access the private pixel data of the base image class.
int mosaicWidth = displayed->getWidth() / blockWidth * FILLER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
int mosaicHeight = displayed->getHeight() / blockHeight * FILLER_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
//mosaic->createNewImage(mosaicWidth, mosaicHeight);

for (int i = 0; i < mosaicHeight; i = i + blockHeight)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mosaicWidth; j = j + blockWidth)
    {
        for (int blockrow = 0; blockrow < blockHeight; blockrow++)
        {
            for (int blockcol = 0; blockcol < blockWidth; blockcol++)
            {
                mospix = headpix;
            }
        }
    }
    displayed = mosaic;
}
displayed = mosaic;
```

I keep running into the problem of attempting to write to protected data; how can I modify the pixel data of mosaic? I'm not allowed to edit the base image class, just the filler image class. I apologize if my post is poorly formatted, this is my first time asking for help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the image class header. I'm not allowed to modify this in any way, and it does not contain a setter for the pixel data.

```
    #include "globals.h"
    #include "pixel.h"

    using namespace std;

    class image { 
public:
    image();            //the image constructor (initializes everything)
    image(string filename);  //a image constructor that directly loads an image from disk
    ~image();           //the image destructor  (deletes the dynamically created pixel array)

    void createNewImage(int width, int height); //this function deletes any current image data and creates a new blank image
                                                //with the specified width/height and allocates the needed number of pixels
                                                //dynamically.
    bool loadImage(string filename);        //load an image from the specified file path.  Return true if it works, false if it is not a valid image.
                                            //Note that we only accept images of the RGB 8bit colorspace!
    void saveImage(string filename);       //Save an image to the specified path
    pixel** getPixels();                    //return the 2-dimensional pixels array
    int getWidth();                     //return the width of the image
    int getHeight();                    //return the height of the image

    void viewImage(CImage* myImage);  //This function is called by the windows GUI.  It returns the image in format the GUI understands.


private:
    void pixelsToCImage(CImage* myImage);  //this function is called internally by the image class.
                                            //it converts our pixel object array to a standard BGR uchar array with word spacing.
                                            //(Don't worry about what this does)
    pixel** pixels;             // pixel data array for image 
    int width, height;      // stores the image dimensions 




    };

    #endif
```

Comment: Have a better llok at your image class.  Unfortunately we cannot help if we don't have the api.

Comment: I posted the image class header. I've been over it more times than I can count. This part of the project has hung me up for the past week or so, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Doesn't `mospix[x][y]= my_new_pixel_value` work?

Comment: the `getPixel()` doesn't return a const pointer.  So there is no problem using the pointer received to write on the picture. In fact this approach seems to correspond to the design of this class.

Comment: Okay, so mospix does receive the values from the filler image. But how do I assign those values to the mosaic pixels? Right now as I step through the program, the values for mospix change to those of the filler image, but the values in the mosaic image do not change.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access to the pixels is via `getPixel()`:

- You can definitively read from it.
- As this member function doesn't return a `const` pointer, and in absence of documentation, I assume that you can write on it as well.

With the following statement, you get access to the pixel array of `mosaic`.

```
    pixel** mospix = mosaic->getPixels();
```

From that moment onwards, you can read/write any pixel directly by using `mospix[i][j]`, as long as `0 <= i && i < mosaic->getHeight() && 0<=j && j<mosaic->getWidth()`.

There is however a serious problem in your code. In the nested loops, your inner statement is:

```
            mospix = headpix;
```

This doesn't copy the current pixel as you seem to expect.  It replaces the pointer that you had correctly initialized, with a copy of the pointer `headpix`.  From then onwards, if you would access to a `mospix` array element, you would in reality let the picture inside `mosaic` unchanged, but you would access pixels in `head->data` !

I don't know exactly how you want to create the mosaic, but I think that there is a mismatch in the way you loop and could imagine that you wanted to say woemething like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mosaic->getHeight(); i = i + blockHeight)
{
    for (int blockrow = 0; blockrow < blockHeight; blockrow++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mosaic->getWidth(); j = j + blockWidth)
        {
            for (int blockcol = 0; blockcol < blockWidth; blockcol++)
            {
                mospix[i+blockrow][j+blockcol] = headpix[blockrow][blockcol];
            }
        }
    }
}
displayed = mosaic;  // Not sure it's needed: both are pointers pointing to the same object
```